# how do emails with + in them works e.g "support+id160211@somedomain.com"

Tags: php, email

How these dynamic looking emails works? what the role of this + symbol in the email addresses.

As it seems it's not a real email inbox who receives these emails.

My thinking is these will go to "support@somedomain.com" as I read it somewhere. but what's the point then. I mostly see this where you open some support ticket or thread and you can directly reply to the email you receive and you email reply is added to the thread/ticket..

But I still don't get how this works behind the scene.

I am looking to implement something similar in my application where a user can reply to the email ( I am not sure what I should be putting for the reply address when I send original mail) we sent and then I want to catch the reply or read it somehow in my script so that I can save it as a comment to the thread.

I use sendmail to send the emails and currently from address is set to 'support@somedomain.com'.. somedomain.com is purchased from bluehost and it's mx records are set to that of provided by google apps..

and I have no idea what's the next step for me.

Comment: Don't know about "somedomain.com" but Gmail redirects all email that looks like "jon+doe@gmail.com" to address "jon@gmail.com" so said user can filter by whatever comes after the +. Check https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en

Comment: No, it's anything anything defined in the SMTP standard. The owner of an e-mail address can handle it however he wants. For example, a typical feature is the catch-all address: all mail that's not sent to a list of defined addresses is redirected to a give one, rather than bounced. Said that, you really need to be more specific in your question. It doesn't make much sense to write a mail server in PHP but your current server (whatever it is... if you have one) can probably link addresses to scripts.

Comment: if you are working with email you should read the relevant RFCSs.  Look at sub-addressing in RFC 5233,  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5233

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` sign, and anything after it, should be ignored. This is a feature for the end user (the email address owner).

This allows `user@gmail.com` to register `user+stackoverflow@gmail.com` with email delivered to `user@gmail.com` but allowing the recipient to see where it was registered. If the address gets passed on (e.g. to spammers), then you can see where your address was sourced from.

Not all (in fact, very few) MTA's support this despite it being the standard in [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2) and [RFC 5233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233#section-4).

[RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2) tells us that the following are allowed as long as they act as a "tokenization point" (i.e. not the start or end of the user before the @ sign):

```
! # $ % & ' * + - / = ?  ^ _ ` . { | } ~
```

[gMail supports this](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html), but it's the only one I know of.

---

You say you want to implement email-to-PHP. You have two options that I would suggest:

1. [php.net/imap](http://php.net/imap)
   Direct all email into an IMAP mailbox and use
   PHP to open the mailbox, read the email and pass it's contents. Easy, reliable (as email is always stored) but not instant (this would likely be triggered by a cron every `n` minutes).
2. [Email Piping](http://www.phpshare.org/articles/Piping-Incoming-Mail-with-PHP)
   If you have access to manage your server, or cPanel, then you can direct email to a PHP script to read the email. This is instant but requires more configuration on the server and if the script is not available then the email is bounced.

I use option 2 myself as the instant parsing of the email is more important to me.

To store an identifier within the email (in this case a thread id) you can use a `reply-to` address as you suggest (using `support+12345@domain.com` with `support@domain.com` being the email address and `12345` being the thread id) or you can store the thread id in the subject or body of the email.

In my situation, I use `abc123@subdomain.domain.com` with `abc123` being a hash of what I need (user id and thread id in your example) with any email sent to `*@subdomain.domain.com` directed to the web server which in turn directs to a PHP Email Piping script.

Your choice which route to take, but the links are there to help you further.

Comment: Interesting... I wasn't aware that it was part of any standard. What section describes it? "Find in Page" for a literal "+" doesn't find a lot...

Comment: My mistake, its [RFC 5322](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.2), answer updated.

Comment: iCloud supports the `+` as well. Yahoo! Mail uses the `-` instead.

Comment: @egg thanks.. that helps.. Can you suggest how I can use this thing to solve my need. As we are already using google app for our emails do we need to enable something for this thing to work for our domain?

Comment: I've updated my answer with how this can help you - and other options available to you.